# TFS 2010 Cannot Create Backup Plan

Tags: tfs

I have recently moved our TFS 2010 server to new server, I'm trying to create a backup plan but TFS tells me that A backup plan already exists for this Tfs configuration.

[image: Backup Plan error]

How can I overwright the existing backup plan?

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is an intresting one. The tool has a feature to prevent multiple backup plans from being created for the same TFS databases (because they might interfere).  It works by setting an extended attribute in the TFS Configuration SQL database (called TFS_BACKUP_PLAN_CONTROLLER) that identifies a configured backup plan.  You can't configure another backup plan from a different machine.  To do it, you will need to delete this extended attribute using SQL Server Management Studio.

You can use the following command to delete the attribute by,

```
Use Tfs_Configuration
```

EXEC sp_dropextendedproperty @name = 'TFS_BACKUP_PLAN_CONTROLLER'

HTH.
Cheers, Tarun

Comment: Thanks Tarun it works. It is the second time you help me. I owe you ;)

Comment: hahaha... Glad i could help. You are already doing a great job by posting very good questions. Keep it up!

Comment: Hi Tarun, I hope you can help me in this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6699755/tfs-2010-cannot-change-accout-identity

Comment: Hi Tarun, I hope you can help me in this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6762644/tfs-2010-web-access-http-403