# TFS 2010 Cannot Change Accout Identity

Tags: tfs

I have recently moved our TFS 2010 server to new server, when I'm trying to configure Reporting server and enter the server name and populate URLs and then press ok, the tfs tells me that user or group is not recognized

[image: Eror]

I tried to run this command

TFSConfig identities /change /fromdomain: OldComputerorDomainName /todomain: NewDomainName /account: OldTFSServiceAccount /toaccount:NewTFSServiceAccount

in order to change the account identity as i moved from a domain to another domain but it doesn't work.

Any ideas how i can solve that?

Comment: Hey mate, have u had a look at this link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404883.aspx. Seems you have run the cmd but just checking.

Comment: yeah Tarun, I have followed these instructions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have run this command

TFSConfig identities /change /fromdomain: OldComputerorDomainName /todomain: NewDomainName

before this command

TFSConfig Accounts /ResetOwner /SQLInstance:ServerName /DatabaseName:DatabaseName

and everything is working now

Answer (score 0):

This is another interesting case. Can you try and connected to the Reporting Services server using SQL Server Management Studio and not Reporting Services administration website. In the root folder permissions, remove the reference to OldComputer\Administrators and added the one to NewComputer\Administrateurs.

HTH
Cheers, Tarun

Comment: What do u mean by "the root folder permissions" I just found 3 folders Jobs, Security, and Shared Schedules.

Comment: By the way, I use SQL Server 2008 R2

Comment: I am sorry my friend, my environment is down so can't try out the scenario. Did you find an answer?

Comment: By root folder i meant security.

Comment: I didn't find an answer yet my friend :( and I can't understand your answer as well :(