# TFS 2010 Web Access HTTP 403

Tags: iis-7, tfs, tfs-web-access

I have recently moved our TFS 2010 server to new server and everything is going well and I can access the tfs through team explorer.However, when I try to access the tfs web access It gives me HTTP 403 error.

[image]

How can I solve this and why this happens?

Answer (score 0):

Can you run fiddler when you try and access through web access. And see how it is calling. We will know if it is using the correct url for the service. This will help begin debugging the root cause.

Comment: Also to confirm, what Web Access URL do you see on the TFS Administration console, is it same as the one you are trying to access?

Comment: And Confirm that you have read access on the port that is exposed for web access. It could be as simple as fire wall blocking this port. You could run a telnet or something to find out whether the port is open for communication.

Comment: I make sure of everything and everything is well configured :(

Comment: everything is working right and I can access all the project collections through Team Explorer and through TFS Workbench by Scrum For Team System, but the web access still not work

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by adding IP address for the server to allowed IP Addresses in IP Address and Domain Restrictions settings in IIS for the Team Foundation Server Site.